# trying to install R package from archive

Tags: r

I want to use the R package frailtySurv. It has been removed from CRAN but there are archived versions at

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/

I tried various methods of installing the package using the install.packages command. In one attempt, I downloaded the *.tar.gz file to my computer, extracted the relevant folder from this file, zipped it and then ran

```r
install.packages('frailtySurv.zip', repos=NULL)
```

I got a message that the package was installed successfully, but when I did

```r
library(frailtySurv)
```

I got a message that the package does not exist.

In another attempt, I tried

```r
install.packages('frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz',
  repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/')
```

and I got the error message

> unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/src/contrib

I made a few other attempts without success.

I'll be grateful if someone can tell me how to do this properly.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Merely unpacking and zipping the package won’t work. You either need to perform a source installation, or you need to *build* the package yourself in a separate step, zip the resulting folder, and install *that*. But in general packages are archived for a reason and won’t install cleanly on new versions of R.

Answer (score 2):

Since the package was archived *recently* (i.e. it's not too far out of sync with current versions of R) and for non-fatal reasons (i.e., warnings rather than complete failures), you should be able to install the most recent versions without too much trouble.

You will need development tools (compilers etc.) installed in order to install the package from source, but if you do then

```r
install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz')
```

or

```r
## if necessary install 'remotes' package first
while (!require("remotes")) {
   install.packages("remotes")
}
remotes::install_version("frailtySurv", "1.3.7")
```

should both work. Alternately, downloading the tarball (i.e. frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz) and running `install.packages("frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz", repos = NULL)` (assuming the .tar.gz file is in your working directory) should work.

All of these options install from source, so require compilation tools.

If installing compilation tools is too burdensome, you should currently (mid-2023) be able to use the [groundhog](https://groundhogr.com/) package, referring to a date before the archiving date of 2023-04-05:

```r
library(groundhog)
groundhog.library("frailtySurv", "2023-04-01")
```

(but note this will install a local version of the package and *all of its dependencies* as of this date ...)

Comment: What compilation tools do I need to install and how do I do that? I installed Rtools if that will help.

Comment: If you have successfully installed current Rtools (on Windows, instructions are different for other OS) you should be good to go.

Comment: got error msg. looks like R doesn't recognize that Rtools is installed remotes::install_version("frailtySurv", "1.3.7") Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘remotes’ > install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz')  [SNIP]
Error in download.file(p, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/frailtySurv/frailtySurv_1.3.7.tar.gz'

Comment: can I download and install locally?

Comment: Do you have a network problem of some sort?  You can download and install locally, but only if you have Rtools installed (note `remotes` and Rtools are two different things)

Comment: Success! I replace Rtools42 with Rtools43 and then the remotes::etc command worked. Thanks for the help.